# How to make a web form submit itself automatically up on a dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms, form-submit

I have a form in my page like the one below;

```
<form name="testform" id="testform" action="test.php" method="get">
  <input name="field1" id="field1" type="text" value="">
  <input name="field2" id="field2" type="text" value="">
  <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <option value="option1" selected="selected">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="Submit">
</form>
```

I want the form to get submitted automatically when user select an option from the drop-down menu. How can I do this with or without using JavaScript (with or without jQuery)?

Thanks in advance... `:)`

blasteralfred

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click (or select)? In that case the user would not be able to make any selection. You probably mean as soon as another option is selected. If so

```
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

If [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) is being used, unobtrusive event handler [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) should be used instead of inline javascript.

```
$(function(){
    $("#dropdown").change( function(e) {
        this.form.submit();
    });
});
```

Use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on) if the form elements are dynamically being added in the DOM

```
$(function(){
    $('#testform').on( "change", "#dropdown", function(e) {
        this.form.submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Javascript event handling should never be performed inline.

Comment: @ChrisCox Blunt statements are more powerful when followed by an argument.

Comment: Fair point. Ok, inline event handlers blur the separation of concerns, are harder to maintain as they're sprinkled into the source of various templates and add bloat to the document, whereas unobtrusive event handlers in an external file are cacheable, logically separated and generally regarded as best practice.

Comment: This simple question seems to be getting some traffic. Updated the answer to include the jQuery alternatives. @Chris, everyone is allowed to edit anything so you are welcome to edit and add more clarification or examples.

Answer (score 7):

You will need to use the jQuery change() event.

```
('#dropdown').change( function() { ('#testform').submit(); })
```

Answer (score 3):

I think

```
$('#dropdown').change(function () { $('Submit').click(); } );
```

will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Here Answer

```
<form name="testform" id="testform" action="test.php" method="get">
              <input name="field1" id="field1" type="text" value="">
              <input name="field2" id="field2" type="text" value="">
              <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" onChange="document.testform.submit()">
            <option value="option1" selected="selected">option1</option>
            <option value="option2">option2</option>
            <option value="option3">option3</option>
            </select>
  </form>
```